# Error when runnin Arm-Based Network Meta-Analysis for Binary Outcomes

Tags: r

I am trying to perform a  network meta analysis in R using the package "pcnetmeta".

It is a meta analysis of different studies (8) on the same treatment. I would like to plot 95% credible intervals (CIs) for the treatment-specific effect sizes.

I have a simple data set, it is the following:
[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlr8C.jpg)

```
s.id    t.id    r   n
1   1   0   60
2   1   1   100
3   1   6   264
4   1   2   108
5   1   3   73
6   1   6   241
7   1   10  317
8   1   2   71
```

Where "s.id"=study identification number, "t.id" = treatment ID (there is only one treatment), "r"=number of events for each study & "n"=the number of patients enrolled in each study.

I run the following code, which is really similar to the example from the introduction to the package "pcnetmeta" but I get the following error message:

> Error in jags.model(file = textConnection(modelstring), data = data.jags,  : 
>     unused argument (n.iter = n.burnin)

I use the following code:

```
# Abs Plot
# increase n.iter to reach convergence
# increase n.adapt to enhance efficiency
set.seed(1234)
nma.out <- nma.ab.bin(s.id, t.id, r, n, data = data,
trtname = c("treatment"), param= "AR", 
model = "het_cor", n.adapt = 400, n.iter = 100, n.chains = 1)

absolute.plot(nma.out)
absolute.plot(nma.out, alphabetic = FALSE)
```

The code is the same as the example from the data package (below), I have only adapted it to my dataset:

```
data(smoke)
# increase n.iter to reach convergence
# increase n.adapt to enhance efficiency
set.seed(1234)
nma.out <- nma.ab.bin(s.id, t.id, r, n, data = smoke,
trtname = c("NC", "SH", "IC", "GC"), param= "AR",
model = "het_cor", n.adapt = 400, n.iter = 100, n.chains = 1)
absolute.plot(nma.out)
absolute.plot(nma.out, alphabetic = FALSE)
```

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pcnetmeta/pcnetmeta.pdf

I tried to do some de-bugging but I cannot find the problem.

Could you please help me?

Thank you!

Christian

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, unfortunately the error message which **pcnetmeta** package giving is not informative at all.

To understand the underlying problem, I ran the source code of **nma.ab.bin** step by step using your data. Note that, this package actually uses [JAGS](http://mcmc-jags.sourceforge.net) program to fit arm-based NMA models via Bayesian inference.
The resulting JAGS error is following:

```
RUNTIME ERROR:
Non-conforming parameters in distribution dwish
```

[You can read a very similar problem and it's solution from here](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcmc-jags/discussion/610037/thread/67d8fff3/). When we look at the JAGS code used in the pcnetmeta:

```
T[1:ntrt,1:ntrt]~dwish(I[1:ntrt,1:ntrt],ntrt+1)
```

we can see that it is related to `dwish`. By the way, JAGS syntax is very similar to R syntax. Here `ntrt` variable is the number of treatment of your data. So in your case it is just 1. By default, **nma.ab.bin** uses Wishart (`dwish`) distribution for the variance covariance matrix of random effects. Apparently there is a problem related to `dwish`, and this is because `ntrt = 1`. To make it work, `ntrt` must be bigger than 1.

Bottom line is that you should have at least two treatments to use **nma.ab.bin**. This makes senses, since when you look at the title of the reference paper of the **pcnetmeta** package:

```
Network meta-analysis of randomized clinical trials: Reporting the proper summaries
```

As you can see, it is NMA of randomized clinical trials (RCTs). And RCTs, by definition, has at least two treatment arms (usually one placebo and one is experimental). Of course there are one-arm trials, but they are not randomized (because you randomize with what, right).